# Android launching activity on top of other activities when handling android.intent.action.VIEW

Tags: android, android-intent

I have MainActivity (let's call it A) that launches other activities and handles `android.intent.action.VIEW`. Now, I'm currently in state where two more activities are launched, A launched B, and then B launched C:

```
A -> B -> C
```

Now, let's say Activity C triggers `android.intent.action.VIEW`... in response Activity A should launch activity D as the last Activity of the stack so that situation ends up being:

```
A -> B -> C -> D
```

However, what happens is that I seem to end up in situation where Activity A spawns on top and then spawns D on top of it, so that my "stack" seems to look like:

```
B -> C -> A -> D
```

When I press back button instead of going back to C, I somehow end up in Activity A. Also, new `onNewIntent` triggers on `Activity A` but so do `onStart` & `onResume`.

Is there a way around this? Or should I somehow differently handle `android.intent.action.VIEW`? I simply want to launch Activity D on top of Activity C and when back button is pressed return to Activity C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem by designating `Activity A` as `singleInstance`. Also, I've changed other activities `launchMode` to `singleTop` and now everything works as expected. This article helped:

[Understand Android Activity's launchMode: standard, singleTop, singleTask and singleInstance](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can start Activity D when press something in Activity C. Then should works as you want.

Comment: I wish I could do that everywhere - unfortunately I need to launch that new Activity from A or wherever I handle `android.intent.action.VIEW`

Comment: you can do it , you are getting this sequence B -> C -> A -> D when user press back button from D ,he goes to activity A in activity a you can use OnActivityForResult method whicjh will trigger only when you are returning from Activity D to Activity A ,In onActivity A own OnActivityForResult you fire intent for the ActivityC

Answer (score 0):

Use a listener that register `Activity C` in `Activity A`. Notify the Listener so that `Activity C` can start the `Activity D` which is triggered by `Activity A`